# How to send data even when joystick is not moving?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small webpage that has a joystick in it and when the joystick moves I want to send a message to a websocket server. To create the joystick I am using `nipple.js`.

I ran into a problem when the joystick reaches the border then it stops moving and emitting `move` events, thought I want to keep sending messages to the websocket with the direction of the joystick.

Basically, the the joystick is used to move a character which is on the server and if the user holds the joystick outside the range of the nipple then I still want to capture that event and send it in through the websocket.

I tried a couple of different ways but got nowhere.

```js
let manager = nipplejs.create(options);

manager.on("move", () => {
  console.log("moved");
});
```

In the above example, if you hold the joystick at some point then it stops emitting events.

```js
const manager = nipplejs.create({
  zone: document.getElementById("container"),
  color: "rgb(14 116 144)"
});

manager.on("move", () => {
  console.log("moved");
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(203 213 225);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nipplejs/0.10.0/nipplejs.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Save the last joystick position, and send it every few milliseconds or save the last position in the backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a event for that, but maybe this could help you.

The idea is to use the `move` event to set the position data. Then you use the `start` an interval that will keep sending the data until the user release the joystick (`end` event).

```js
const manager = nipplejs.create({
  zone: document.getElementById("container"),
  color: "rgb(14 116 144)"
});

let pos = {};
let interval;

manager.on("move", (evt, data) => {
  pos = data.position;
});

manager.on("start", () => {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(pos);
  }, 100)
})
manager.on("end", () => {
  clearInterval(interval);
})
```

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(203 213 225);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nipplejs/0.10.0/nipplejs.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```